# Login to OpenERP from another website

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

After a lot of research, i coudn't find any useful information that could be of use onto my problem.

I am trying to create a login page that redirects to my website. After the user is logged in, that user has access to OpenERP and the whole website.

Any information is useful. I don't understand Python.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i think you need top work out on openerp API Configuration

that will help you

Comment: How do i do that? What kind of configurationsdo i need to make?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ldap kind of things openerp supports oauth2 check [here](http://jignesh-openerp.blogspot.in/2013/03/oauth2-openerp.html)

Comment: I am using LDAP to login to OpenERP. The thing is, i want to login from another page.

Comment: then you have to create an api to call openerp  login using the api(XMLRPC)